# How to get title and description value of label in blogspot?

Tags: blogger

I want to get the value of the title and description of the label in blogspot after optimizing the meta tag as below

```
<title>Nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa bán nhà quận Gò vấp</title>
<meta content='Bán nhà Gò Vấp giá rẻ, mua nhà ở Gò Vấp chính chủ sổ hồng sổ đỏ tại nhadatsonnghia.com' name='description'/>
```

I tried `<data:title/>` and `<data:description/>` like this [document](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en) but it's not working. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var t = document.title;
alert(t);
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  txt = txt + "Content of "+(i+1)+". meta tag: "+x[i].content+"<br>";
alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: hey bro, I want to get the value to insert into another code, do not want to display a alert, how to output the value?

Comment: According you question I send the answer .Any way thanks

Answer (score 2):

`<data:view.title/>` The title of current page.

`<data:view.search.label/>` The label name of current **label** page.

`<data:blog.metaDescription/>` The search description of the blog on multiple posts pages **or** the search description of post on single post pages.

Comment: Hey @Bassam `<data:view.title/>` = `<data:blog.title/>` = the blog title, not the current page title :( I want to show the title of the label as the content of the `<title>` tag above `<title>Nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa bán nhà quận Gò vấp</title>`

Comment: Previous tags work differently on different pages types. Like `data:view.title` shows blog title on index pages but it shows the post title on post pages. Also, `data:view.search.label` works only on label pages not on single post page.